# EF6 Code First Audit Table Per Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a requirement that feels like it probably has a simpler solution with EF than what we're currently using.

Essentially, as an auditing requirement, for any entity that inherits from a given base class, I need to create both the entity's table itself, but also a table that's identical, but with 3 additional columns - a FK back to the original entity's table, a description (e.g. "Modified", "Added", "Deleted") and an XML column that will contain a serialized version of the state of the entity.

At present, we're manually adding the entities to create the audit tables (currently inherit from an AuditableEntity class and developers have to manually ensure that other fields match the original entity) and using migrations to add T-SQL triggers to the entity tables to update the data in the audit tables on any insert, update, delete.

I'd prefer if I could somehow get EF to automatically create/migrate the audit tables based on the entity tables without having to manually sync them, and likewise use an interceptor or something similar to update the audit table on insert/update/delete of an entity rather than using triggers.  Does anyone know if this is possible, or done anything similar?  In the past, the closest I've come is a single, common audit history table which wasn't too bad.

Comment: did you give a try to sql cdc : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc645937

Comment: you could override SaveChanges() as well. https://jmdority.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-change-tracking-for-audit-logging/

Comment: CDC looks like it may be a possibility.  Overriding SaveChanges as described in the article Steve has linked to is what I've done in the past, but relies on an entity being specifically built either for a generic 'AuditLog' as per their example, or for something similar to the case I'm trying to model, an almost identical entity per table that I'm trying to audit, so doesn't really get me anywhere I'm afraid.

Comment: Take a look at [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#auditentityframework) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

This project may answer to your requirement. You can access to all auditing information like entity name, action name, property name, original and current values, etc.

A lot of options is available like an AutoSave all information in the database.

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

var ctx = new EntityContext();
// ... ctx changes ...

var audit = new Audit();
audit.CreatedBy = "ZZZ Projects"; // Optional
ctx.SaveChanges(audit);

// Access to all auditing information
var entries = audit.Entries;
foreach(var entry in entries)
{
    foreach(var property in entry.Properties)
    {
    }
}
```

Documentation: [EF+ Audit](http://entityframework-plus.net/audit)

Comment: Marking as answer.  Ended up writing a very similar bespoke solution.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution. My issue is that I inherited an Oracle database and converted it to SQL Server using SSMA-Oracle. It has finance data from 2012 to date. Every table has at least 2 column-composite PK. and go up to 12. Does this solution work with composite PKeys?

Comment: Did you try it @DoomerDGR8? Yes, it should.

Answer (score 1):

You could create one table with the columns:

- Id
- TableName
- Action (Add, update, delete)
- IdOfRecord
- XmlSerialized
- DateChanges (use datetime2)

Then override SaveChanges() to write each change to that one table.

No need to mess around with keeping Audit table schema up to date when running migrations etc

Comment: Problem with this approach is scale.  Once you get to, say, 1m entities, each with numerous child entities (some of which regularly reach into the 100s per parent entity), that single audit table is going to become very unwieldy very quickly.  Reads and writes become painfully slow.  Not saying it's necessarily wrong for every scenario, but definitely not right for mine.

Comment: Hmmm if you could only serialize the FK ids (not the whole child object) that may not be so bad, but starting to head into yak shaving teritory.